# Move ether from mytetherwallet coldstored on computer after one year, after the fork

Tags: ether, dao, myetherwallet

I have had ether coldstored on my computer with myetherwallet for a year or so, since the fork I remember there was a need to update before sending the ether but I can't find any instructions or information about it anymore. If it was sent without first updating they'd be lost is what I heard.
So what is it I need to do? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

[You need to split your ETH from your ETC.](https://medium.com/@timonrapp/how-to-deal-with-the-ethereum-replay-attack-3fd44074a6d8#.sectz2b77) This is to avoid replay attacks. Aside from that your ok. You can send your funds without loosing them. If you are running a client, like Go or Parity you need to update that, but you said you are just using myetherwallet.com.

Answer (score 1):

From [Replay protection question on MyEtherWallet](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5rtgya/replay_protection_question_on_myetherwallet/) :

> Both chains are now automatically protected from replays via eip155 on MyEtherWallet. No need to split anymore.

Make sure that you use the correct URL https://www.myetherwallet.com as there are similar sounding phishing sites.

You don't have to do anything. You may however want to move your coins on one of the chains just to separate them a bit more.